# ERROR: TensorFlow with ML Compute acceleration is only available on macOS 11.0 and later

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, apple-m1

Downloaded Tensor Flow mac release package (https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/releases), open the tensorflow_macos-0.1alpha3.tar.gz package, run the 'install_venv.sh' script, and get the following error **ERROR: TensorFlow with ML Compute acceleration is only available on macOS 11.0 and later.**

I am running this inside a conda environment with python 3.8 (I've tried 3.7-3.11 with same outcome).

I would post on apple github repo but it's been publicly archived, so assuming this just is no longer available?

I've tried running this inside a conda environment with python 3.8 (I've tried 3.7-3.11 with same outcome).

I'm expecting that the install would be successful. I tried installing pip install tensorflow (i.e. no mac specific) and pyCharm sees the lib tensorflow but I get
**Apple M1: process finished with exit code 132 (interrupted by signal 4: sigill** which the solution is to install the package from above: `https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/issues/270`

Comment: Hi Michael! You can opt for [metal plugin instructions](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/) if you are trying to install Tensorflow in Mac M1.